# Installing node-ffi on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, node-ffi

I'm trying to install node-ffi on my Windows development machine, but the install fails. According to the [node-ffi webpage](https://npmjs.org/package/node-ffi), Windows should be supported. However, it appears that gyp is trying to execute something through "sh", which (obviously) is not present on my system. Any ideas?

```
D:\code\ffi-test>npm install node-ffi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-ffi
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-ffi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings

> node-ffi@0.5.7 install D:\code\ffi-test\node_modules\node-ffi
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\code\ffi-test\node_modules\node-ffi>node "D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_module
s\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.13/node-v0.10.13.tar.gz
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.13/node-v0.10.13.tar.gz
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.13/node.lib
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.13/x64/node.lib
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.13/node.lib
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.13/x64/node.lib
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.13/node.lib
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.13/node.lib
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.13/x64/node.lib
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.13/x64/node.lib
sh gjenkjennes ikke som en intern eller ekstern kommando,
kjørbart program eller satsvis fil.
gyp: Call to 'sh libffi-config.sh' returned exit status 1. while trying to load
binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_module
s\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:415:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\code\ffi-test\node_modules\node-ffi
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.13
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.2
gyp ERR! not ok
unbuild node-ffi@0.5.7
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0

D:\code\ffi-test>
```

My system is Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in cmd set Visual Studio path depending upon ur version as

```
Visual Studio 2010 (VS10): SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS100COMNTOOLS%

Visual Studio 2012 (VS11): SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS110COMNTOOLS%

Visual Studio 2013 (VS12): SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS120COMNTOOLS%
```

Check if python is installed and configured .

Python version <3 is required

then in cmd use command

```
npm install ffi
```

to install ffi . 
For more help look at 
[Cannot install node modules that require compilation on Windows 7 x64/VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012/29631083#29631083)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with

```
npm install ffi
```

Watch the documentation:
https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi

Comment: Thanks, that got me a bit further! Now its complaining that I'm missing VS2010, but that I think I can amend :)

Answer (score 0):

For visual studio 2017 try this in powershell to set environment variable

```
set VS150COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\
```

and then run the npm command

```
npm install ffi
```