# 'The specified module could not be found' error when using 'scrypt' module in node.js

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, scrypt

I'm trying to use 'scrypt' module. The problem is that when I try to run my nodejs application (node app.js), I get this error:

```
C:\Users\A\Documents\B\C>node app.js

module.js:356
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                               ^
Error: The specified module could not be found.
C:\Users\A\Documents\B\C\node_modules\scrypt\build\Release\scry
pt.node
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\A\Documents\B\C\node_module
s\scrypt\index.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I installed 'scrypt' module with this line:

```
npm install scrypt -msvs_version=2012
```

the -msvs_version is taken [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012)

Comment: Sounds like it didn't compile (correctly). Did you try installing under the Windows SDK command prompt?

Comment: @mscdex What did u mean 'installing under the Windows SDK'? Install what? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio Express (2012), you should have installed the Windows SDK. When you install the SDK, it comes with its own command prompt (in your start menu) that pre-sets some environment variables for compiling. node-gyp/npm needs to be ran under this command prompt for compilation to work correctly.

Comment: Also, what node version (`node -v`) do you have?

Comment: node version: v0.10.26

Comment: I tried running 'npm install' from the Windows SDK Command Prompt, and running 'node app.js', but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [this node-scrypt issue](https://github.com/barrysteyn/node-scrypt/issues/50).

According to what is said there, you should be able to solve your problem by

- either installing [OpenSSL for Windows](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)
- or installing and building with Visual Studio 2010