# node.js TypeError: Object has no method get

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to separate server initiation and other calls from the core file(`app.js`) but when I try to run it, it issues me error that 
`http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
                                                 ^
TypeError: Object function (){ all code from app.js file }`
 `has no method 'get'`

This is  `app.js` file.

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/
module.exports = function(){
    var express = require('express');
    var routes = require('./routes');
    var path = require('path');
    var app = express();

    // all environments
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    // development only
    if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
        app.use(express.errorHandler());
    }
    app.get('/', routes.index);
    return app;
};
```

and this is `server.js` file.

```
var http = require('http'),
    app = require('./app');
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

using `express@3.4.0`

what am I missing OR doing wrong.. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a function to `module.exports`, so when you `require('./app')`, you need to call it like a function:

```
var http = require('http'),
    app = require('./app')();
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: thank, worked..and if I don't want to call it like function then what I'll have to change in`app.js`?

Comment: See @lante answer. Personally, when I separate modules, I like to have functions as it allows me to pass in arguments and use arguments in the `app.js` file.

Comment: yes, got that,I'll also pass an argument,not now, so this approach seems to be nicer..

Comment: I'm using it on `Linux Mint 17`. I ran this on `Windows 7` and when I try to install `connect-mongoose` it says that I should have `.Net framework 2.0` installed, but I've installed it already. any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds like a different question ;) However, not being familiar with the `connect-mongoose` package, it sounds like it's trying to compile a native module. So you'll need either Visual Studio or the Windows SDKs. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012

Answer (score 3):

You have no reason to return a function into your `app.js` file, just return the **express** object:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// ... more variables

// ... the rest of your code

module.exports = app;
```

Then, the rest of your code into `server.js` will work fine.

Remember that `module.exports` works like a "`return`" into CommonJS (and therefore NodeJS).

See [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).