# NPM Install on Windows 7 issue, no Microsoft.CPP folder

Tags: c++, node.js, visual-studio, msbuild, npm

I'm having troubles with npm install on Windows 7.
I'm using **Visual Studio 2013 Express** and I've also installed **Microsoft Build Tools 2013**.
I have the Path variable set and I've tried with the --msvs_version parameter in the npm install

It gives me the

error MSB4019: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" not found

That folder doesn't exist on my computer, I only have
**MSBuild\12.0**
and
**MSBuild\Microsoft**

What do I miss to install?? I would be able to compile Node project without having to install the full version of VS, if possible, and honestly, I would be able to do it by installing the minimum required software.

Thank you!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012) might help.

Comment: @BenFortune I updated the question, I already tried with the msvs parameter, no luck. Problem is that the cpp folder is missing