# Atom install packages fails every time

Tags: installation, atom-editor

Environment is Windows 7 64bit and atom 1.0.5
atom can be used normally, but can not install any package.

**error info：**

```
    Installing “vim-mode@0.57.0” failed.Hide output…

    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp info using node-gyp@1.0.2
    gyp info using node@0.10.35 | win32 | ia32
    gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.22.0/node-v0.22.0.tar.gz
    gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.22.0/node-v0.22.0.tar.gz
    gyp WARN install
    Compiler tools not found
    Packages that depend on modules that contain C/C++ code will fail to install.
    Read here for instructions on installing Python and Visual Studio.
    Run apm install --check after installing to test compiling a native module.
```

`apm -v`output：

```
    apm  1.0.1
    npm  2.5.1
    node 0.10.35
    python 2.7.10
    git 1.9.5.msysgit.1
    visual studio 2013
```

Comment: how about this? https://github.com/atom/apm/issues/322#issuecomment-96430856

Comment: how about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
apm config set msvs_version 2013
```

or version you have installed

Here you have version strings:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/9049241f9181456a6fbe3b263bcedae504e0c571/gyp/pylib/gyp/MSVSVersion.py#L229

Another link [Cannot install node modules that require compilation on Windows 7 x64/VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012)

Answer (score 0):

how about this

Attention:Windows only

such as ${basedir}/AtomSetup.exe

1.

```
cd ${basedir}
```

2.

```
AtomSetup.exe install
```

Just have a try.