# npm install with error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: windows, npm, npm-install, node-gyp, node-sass

I'm try to install modules on Windows 10 using npm 5.6.0. When I enter npm install I get:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\xiaooming\Desktop\app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\xiaooming\\Desktop\\app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\xiaooming\Desktop\app\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN kingt4.0app@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\xiaooming\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-18T13_02_03_946Z-debug.log
```

It seems like `node-sass` install error. The environment is below:

Python version: 2.7.14

npm version: 5.6.0

node version: 8.10.0

ruby version: 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

system: win10(x64)

node-gyp: 3.6.2

And I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio express 2015,
the below command has been executed：

```
npm config set msvs_version 2015
node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2015
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "kingt4.0app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "an kingt4.0 project.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "finance"
  ],
  "author": "kingdom",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.4.2",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.3.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-file-include": "^0.13.7",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp.spritesmith": "^6.2.1",
    "imagemin-jpegtran": "^4.3.2",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.2.2",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "^4.0.0",
    "spritesheet-templates": "^10.1.2",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "remodal": "^1.0.7",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

How to resolve this problem? thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install node modules that require compilation on Windows 7 x64/VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012)

Comment: use node v7.9.x and install vs2015 and windows sdk then it is ok.

Comment: How the hell node got so popular since it's almost impossible to install standard project in a normal way. -_-

Answer (score 97):

If this is a mac machine (OSX) here is what you can do

use terminal

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

then remove installed version

```
sudo rm -r -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

and reinstall

```
xcode-select --install
```

that should fix the problem

Ref: [gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected macOS Catalina](https://anansewaa.com/gyp-no-xcode-or-clt-version-detected-macos-catalina/)

Comment: Personally, I need to do it couple times per year. ‍♂️

Comment: This command works. But like Mark Twain, I end up repeating it periodically.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Took about a minute to run these commands, so it was super quick. Thanks!

Comment: I never had to do this with my previous osx machine. Now I am doing it daily. :(

Comment: Well looks like I just wiped my command line tools. On MacOS 13.5 the final command just says `error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" in System Settings to install updates`

Answer (score 47):

this works for me. run command below one by one

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm update
npm install
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me.

Comment: removing package-lock.json is asking for more troubles

Answer (score 24):

```
$ npm i --ignore-script
```

I tried different ways to solve this issue, finally, this comment simply help to install node packages without any errors.

Comment: Yes, that does not show any errors. Still, I would not call it a solution. Some script failed and something is still broken/missing. Question is what failed and why.

Answer (score 16):

Try this command below and see if that wiped away this issue. I have catalina on my mac and this command wiped away that problem.

```
npm i -g node-gyp@latest && npm config set node_gyp "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
```

Comment: I ran npm i -g node-pre-gyp@latest and it fixed my issue. This was on a Mac running Big Sur

Comment: @WhatWouldBeCool this worked for me too, on Ventura 13.1

Comment: Looks like `node-pre-gyp` is no longer supported and is replaced by `npm i -g @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@latest`

Answer (score 16):

This error is due to obsolete packages. It can also be due to a version change of NodeJS, npm or other packages and/or package managers. To solve it you must remove `node_modules` and execute the command:

```
npm i --ignore-script
```

It's possible that `node-sass` gives you an error because it is already obsolete, so install npm sass. In case it's another package, just check the current version and update it.

Answer (score 10):

Delete your `$HOME/.node-gyp` directory and try again:

```
rm -R ~/.node-gyp
```

Answer (score 4):

I think delete this directory is better:

```
rm -rf ~/.node-gyp/
rm -r node_modules/.bin/;
rm -r build/
npm install <your module>
```

Answer (score 4):

if you remove your package-lock.json and then run

```
npm update
npm install
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue while installing a project which uses the webpack.
And i did follow the steps about xcode-select reinstallation but it gave me the same error. For this I did a simple fix, I installed node-sass separately as it was the one giving error.

```
npm i node-sass
```

Then ran the installation again using,

```
npm i
```

And it worked for me✌️

Sometimes the node packages have older versions which needs to be upgraded as well for a project. For this you get vulnerability related warnings while installation. for this run the following command(it is also mentioned in terminal output),

```
npm audit fix
```

Comment: I found switching to the new Dart sass worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue where my MSVS_version was 2019.I tried following steps and issue was resolved.

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Then

```
npm config set msvs_version 2017
npm i
```

Comment: My Os: Windows 10.. so, is it necessary to restart after installing windows-build-tools?

Comment: Yess try doing that

Comment: No need for restart on Win 7. Heartfelt thank you for ending 6 hour odyssey to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

This can also occurs if you have Python 3.11 installed, as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74732671/2630344

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install Windows build tools.
Check it out this [ref](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue from a web development context via node-sass or gulp-sass which uses the gyp library that fails to install. **tldr; too old, upgrade to sass** which will avoid the gyp issue

Did some deep investigating on the issue. Several people may have ran into this issue because they're attempting to use `gulp-sass` which depends on `node-sass` in their development and along the way this gyp issue popped up.

Initially in the gulp-sass installation an error popped up complaining that python2.7 was not installed in my computer. Once I installed that, the gyp issue showed up due to an incompatability of the newest node and gyp. My solution was to use the newest gulp with the newest sass. Hope this helps anyone who arrived here from web development.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change `node-sass` to `sass` in your `package.json` as stated on `node-sass`'s official page (see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)):

> **Warning**: LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated. While they will continue to receive maintenance releases indefinitely, there are no plans to add additional features or compatibility with any new CSS or Sass features. Projects that still use it should move onto Dart Sass.

Answer (score 0):

As described here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1634

```
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
gyp: Call to '/usr/bin/pg_config --libdir' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
```

In my case the problem solved by installing `libpq-dev` on my Ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

then try to removing the `node_modules` and do `npm install` again.

**Note**
Please take a note that this is not a problem with the node modules, the problem is on the my machine, it doesn't meet the criteria of `libpq`

Comment: npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/libpq-dev - Not found

Comment: It's not an NPM modules @PirAbdul, it's on your machine. Find a match module for your OS, in my case it's Ubuntu. On yours maybe a little different depending on what you use. Please read carrefully.

Comment: I run sudo apt install libpq-dev - my issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue on my `OSX 10.15` with `brew` as repository; for me was enough doing:

```
brew unlink python@2
brew link python
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to update to dart-sass, was still using node-sass which is deprecated.
https://github.com/sass/dart-sass#from-npm

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue while doing npm install for one of existing vuejs app. Initially it complained for missing python. after installing python, i started getting this error - gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

Later I realized that the project also had package-lock.json. I removed it and did npm install. It worked!!! So if you are facing similar issue, and also have package-lock.json then try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this issue for quite long on `macOS`. For me, on macOS, I had to

1. Install Python 2.7.x while Python 3 was already installed
2. Ensure Python 2 path was included in $PATH
3. Switch CLI. It didn't work in iTerm2, but worked fine on standard macOS terminal

I did install `xcode` as well, but that didn't have an effect

Answer (score 0):

I got the same `gyp ERR!` error on Ubuntu 22 when I was installing [node-heapdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heapdump).

To fix it, I run the following command:

```
 sudo apt install node-gyp
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing the node version.

I use nvm to handle multiple node versions. I was using node v14.x and npm v6.x and I had to change node to 16.x and npm 8.x

I did:

```
nvm use 16
```

If you don't have nvm, you need to install it using brew:

```
brew install nvm
```

I know there could be multiple fixes for this error but this worked for me.

Later edit:
I also switched from node-sass to sass as node-sass is not maintained anymore and the migration is not that complex. You can have a look at how to do this [here](https://dev.to/ccreusat/migrating-from-node-sass-to-sass-dart-sass-with-npm-3g3c).

Answer (score 0):

## macOS install gpu.js

Running on MacOS following these install steps:

1. [install nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating) `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash` then open a new shell session.
2. nvm install 16
3. nvm use 16
4. brew install yarn [OR] `npm install --global yarn`
5. yarn add gpu.js

```bash
node gpu-test.js
```

Test file example `gpu-test.js`:

```js
const { GPU } = require('gpu.js');
const gpu = new GPU();
const multiplyMatrix = gpu.createKernel(function(a, b) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        sum += a[this.thread.y][i] * b[i][this.thread.x];
    }
    return sum;
}).setOutput([2, 2]);

const a = new Array(2).fill(new Array(2).fill(1));
const c = multiplyMatrix(a, a);

console.log(a);
console.log(c);
```

[image: output gpu.js on macOS]

Comment: For centos (yum) there were missing libs: 
1. `sudo yum install libXi-devel mesa-libGL-devel`
2. `nvm install 18.12.1`
3. `nvm use v18.12.1`
4. `sudo yarn add gpu.js`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
1、install corresponding version of node-sass;

see:https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

2、install latest version of sass-loader;

see:https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader

3、install python and add into PATH;

4、run npm install;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my project. The thing is package.json is already installed and dependencies are defined. I found the solution in this article.

https://sebhastian.com/npm-err-code-1/

It suggests to run npx npm-check-updates to update dependencies one by one. Then run npx npm-check-updates -u to update package.json. Then 'npm install' and it runs fine. No error.

Answer (score -1):

For MAC ONLY

Step: 1

```
sudo rm -r -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Step: 2

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

Comment: How can this be helpful? Do you mind explaining your solution. You should this command before --switch command above `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score -1):

If you watch some sort of old tutorial and want to install *webworker-threads* from NPM, you should know that it's a part of Node JS.

```
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');
```

You can see more about differences here
https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html