# AWS API Gateway not found

Tags: aws-lambda, react-native, aws-api-gateway, react-native-ios

Im brand new to AWS API Gateways and Lambda. I am trying to get the basic 'Hello from Lambda!' function to work.

I can sign in successfully as below:

```
const user = await Auth.signIn(email, password);
```

I get A token back which is correct as I tested it on the AWS API console and got the response

```
//token works as tested on AWS Console (API Tester)
        const token = user2.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken
```

I assume that the request info is correct as the token is correct:

```
  const requestInfo = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: token
    }
   }
```

I think the error is here as whenever I try to do anything with the 'Data' I don't get a response

```
 const data = await API.get('API_NAME','/hello',requestInfo)
 console.log('This is the Data: ',{ data } )
```

The Error I get in the try/catch Xcode is:

```
'API API_NAME does not exist'
```

any suggestions?

Error I get when I run Amplify Push:

```
Packaging lambda failed function failed with the error 
Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: APP_NAME@1.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@16.8.6
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"16.8.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.7.0" from @aws-amplify/ui-react@0.2.36
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/ui-react@"^0.2.35" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.14.0" from react-dom@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"^16.7.0" from @aws-amplify/ui-react@0.2.36
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/ui-react@"^0.2.35" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/name/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/name/.npm/_logs/2021-02-02T09_36_01_091Z-debug.log
An error occurred during the push operation: Packaging lambda failed function failed with the error 
Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: APP_NAME@1.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@16.8.6
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"16.8.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.7.0" from @aws-amplify/ui-react@0.2.36
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/ui-react@"^0.2.35" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.14.0" from react-dom@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"^16.7.0" from @aws-amplify/ui-react@0.2.36
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/ui-react@"^0.2.35" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/name/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/name/.npm/_logs/2021-02-02T09_36_01_091Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can sign in successfully I suppose you've configured Amplify something like [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js#re-use-existing-authentication-resource) specifying AWS poolId, clientId etc.

Similarly you've to do for APIs also like documented [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/js#manual-setup-import-existing-rest-api)

This is the format, suppose API name is **account**.

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: { ... },

  API: {
    endpoints: [
      {
        name: 'account', // name of API like 'account', no '/'
        endpoint: BASE_URL, // like 'https://api_name.com', don't put '/' at the end
        region: 'us-east-1', // your region like 'us-east-1', 'ap-southeast-1' etc.
      },
      ... // Other APIs
    ]
  }
});
```

Then when you call the API this would be the format

```
const accountRes: AccountData = await API.get('account', '/account', requestInfo);
```

NOTE:- If API name is same but request type is different (GET, POST, PUT etc.) you don't need to do multiple entries, You can simply call respective method for the request `API.get()`, `API.post()`, `API.put()` etc.

Comment: Hi there! thank you for your help but unfortunately I am doing all of this and it still doesn't work. I tried running amplify push and I get a new error as I have updated my question

Comment: Get this error sometimes in react-native, Don't know exact steps to fix it. try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60482583) or delete **node_modules** then `npm install`.

Comment: Had to start the project again. head is wrecked! would you mind having a look at my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014223/aws-cognito-user-able-to-sign-in-but-api-does-not-exist-when-using-i-can-acce