# "Apply() is only allowed in ready status" (unhandled runtime error)

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I've just started using Gatsby with the [gatsby starter-blog template](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/). I keep getting this error pretty much whenever I change anything but the Markdown files—

[image]

**What causes this error?**

`gatsby clean` and a retstart sometimes solve it; sometimes not.

I'm on MacOS and experienced [this Gatsby installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348482/npm-install-with-error-gyp-failed-with-exit-code-1). However, after much back and forth, I believe I fixed it. Yet I'm not 100% sure. Could this be the cause?

The 'Open in Editor' button doesn't do anything.

I get no error messages upon running `gatsby develop`.

**Edit**: This only happens in Safari.

Comment: Can you provide an example of markdown?

Comment: I had the same and I fix it by remove HTML tag `<base href=...>`. Maybe this is not the best solution, but this was the problem.

Comment: Great. I only get this error in Safari. It appears every time I refresh the site.