# Trouble installing Turbulenz

Tags: python, windows, dll, python-2.7, turbulenz

I was trying out the HTML5 Game Engine Turbulenz, which requires Python to be installed on the machine. I downloaded and installed Python, and then I downloaded the installer for Turbulenz. In the middle of the installation, I get an error that says "Cannot find python.dll". After clicking ok, the installation continued, so I thought it was fine. When I tried to start Turbulenz, I got a new error, saying "env/Scripts/activate.bat" is missing. I Googled the error and found nothing relevant. I remembered the first error, and I went looking for python.dll. Turns out that it is in C:Python27/, where my Python installation is. Can anyone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my honest guess is that you need to make sure that `C:\Python27` is set up in your PATH variable. There's a video link on the official python docs that helps you get there

- http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=960000&fromSeriesID=96

or other StackOverflow answers

- [How do I run a python program in the Command Prompt in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621255/how-do-i-run-a-python-program-in-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7)

once your python folder is added to the path, you should have no problem