# Command Prompt shuts down automatically

Tags: python, command, prompt

Whenever I run python script on windows command prompt, the command prompt shuts down automatically.
Does anybody know the reason? How can continue working on windows command prompt even while my python script is running? Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run a python program in the Command Prompt in Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621255/how-do-i-run-a-python-program-in-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7)

Comment: Are you double clicking the python program to start it? (which might start in a command prompt) or are you opening up cmd then typing "python myscript.py"?

Comment: How are you launching it, through the task bar?