# Python installation will not work, path was changed, can code but can't import

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, pip

I am using windows 8.1 with python 2.7.9 and I think I cannot get python to install/import modules properly. I looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621255/how-do-i-run-a-python-program-in-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7) post and when typing`set PATH` into the cmd prompt it lists ";C:Python27\Scripts\;C:Python27\" I have tried it with just "Python27" or with the "Python27\Scripts" and none of them work.The location of the python application according to its properties is "C:\Python27".

When I type in `python` into the cmd it says "python is not recognized as an internal or external command" which is not supposed to happen according this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddpYVA-7wq4). I can use Pyscripter and type code into the python command line and it works. So the real problem is I cannot import modules. I have tried [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddpYVA-7wq4) video, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwxbD2oc4s4) video and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbL_FTEZSyY) video. All offer different ways of importing modules but none of them work (all do it closer to end of the video). How do I import modules? I know it is supposed to be super easy with pip but it isn't working out for me. What do I do I?

Comment: You are missing the backslash after `C:` in your path variable. It should be `;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\Python27\ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future viewers, the issue was that backslashes were missing from the path variable after `C:`. The path variable was updated to reflect this.

```
;C:Python27\Scripts\;C:Python27\
```

was changed to:

```
;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\Python27\
```