# Trying to access Python through Windows Command Prompt without adding Environment Variable

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to access Python through a Windows command prompt, but am at an office and cannot add an Environment Variable. So, I cant follow the advice provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621255/how-do-i-run-a-python-program-in-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7). Thus, I added a User Environment Variable through User Accounts and use Variable:python and Value: C:\Python33. When I do a Windows Run check on %python% I reach the required Python33 folder. However, when I type `python -Version` in the command prompt I get the error `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run Python from the command prompt and include the full path to python.exe. For example to get the version:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe --version
```

When you run a script you specify the path to the script if you're not in the directory where the script is located. For example, if your script is in `C:\scripts` and is called `my_script.py`:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe C:\scripts\my_script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Python33\python.exe pyscript.py` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting environment variables, you can use the whole path, like Neo wrote e.g.:
 C:\Python33\python.exe yourPythonScript.py

Remove any environment variables you have added.

Answer (score 0):

I once Had a similar problem, but i couldnt find any solution, not even adding the path to the python folder was working.
Then I opened Python and clicked in File, then browser path, and I found that I had another folder that contained the real Python folder, not the default one. Maybe it could work for you too.