# Understing how to search for specific string using find() function in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I study it by myself, and I just want to make sure I understand something about find() function...

If I want to find a specific string, it will find the first index of the first letter/number of the string or the the first time this strings?

for exaple, there's the next given string:
"I$want$moeny$and$food"

If I type find('$')
it will give me the first time '$' showed up in this string, which is 1.

However, if I want to find "$moeny", I will get the the number 6, means python serched where the full "$moeny" string is showed in the first time?

and If I type find('$mommy') it will give me an Error, and not index 1.
Am I right? Did I understand it clearly?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can get answers to all your questions by empirical study: _try it yourself_ - why are you asking here? if you do not have a running python install, use some pyhton online resource like https://pyfiddle.io/  to test your code. SO does not _teach_ programming, it helps fixing mistakes. If you need learning ressources, use the info on the tag: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info and look for learning resources or use the excellent https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is to try it yourself and see what happens.
A good practice is to [enter the CMD or shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621255/how-do-i-run-a-python-program-in-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7) and type "python" and try various commands.