# array python || time.strftime

Tags: python, arrays

i want a print current index of array using:

```
import os
import datetime
import time

a = time.strftime("%d", time.localtime())
list1 = ["123", 123, 123, 132, 123, 123, 123, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print(list1[a])
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

But console is close
What happen?

Comment: What does "*console is close (error)*" mean? Please provide all output (and error messages) that you are getting.

Comment: @uneven_mark Console not have errors.. Console closing. I edited code.

Comment: Python is not responsible for closing your console. What OS are you using and how are you running the script? Try opening a command line and running the script from there, so that you can see all error messages printed, after Python exited.

Comment: @uneven_mark Window 10, how see?

Comment: I am not too familiar with Windows. Try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621255/how-do-i-run-a-python-program-in-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7), although it may be out-of-date for Python 3.x (I don't know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what does it means that the console is closing without an error.

when running you code I get the following, using `python 2.7`:

```
>>> print(list1[a])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

This is caused because the return of `time.strftime("%d", time.localtime())` is a string variable.

The change in your code needs to be:

```
print(list1[int(a)])
```

which will transform that string into an integer.

do notice that there is a lot of issue you need to take care of:

1. make sure that the number string you assigning to `a` is valid
2. make sure you you don't enter an index that does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can pass a string to a list index

```
print(list1[a]) # Lists take integers as indices
```

Comment: As i said you're expilicitly passing a string to an array list[]

Comment: The interpreter is seeing [a] as an integer, so it gives you a Type error!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, i hope it gives you the output you needed!

```
a = int(time.strftime("%d", time.localtime()))
list1 = ["123", 123, 123, 132, 123, 123, 123, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print(list1[a])
```