# How to run a python file in the windows command prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

I was trying to run the python file in the windows command prompt, and I used the command `"test.py"`, with the double quotes in the command.

The file was opened as a `.txt` file with the codes I wrote in it instead of running like a program.

I have put the file on the desktop.

I am very new to coding. Can someone help me with how to run python file from windows cmd prompt?

Comment: You can look for the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621255/how-do-i-run-a-python-program-in-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a Python program in the Command Prompt in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621255/how-do-i-run-a-python-program-in-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running

`python "/path/to/file.py"`?

For python 3, you may have to use

`python3 "/path/to/file.py"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing:

```
"test.py"
```

Use

```
python test.py
```