# run program in Python shell

Tags: python, executable

I have a demo file: `test.py`.
In the Windows Console I can run the file with: `C:\>test.py`

How can I execute the file in the Python Shell instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "the python shell"?  Did you run `python` from the command line?  Or are you using IDLE or some other program which can also provide a Python `>>>` prompt?

Comment: Related posts - [How do I run a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1522564/465053) & [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5458048/465053)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Use [execfile](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#execfile) for **Python 2**:

```
>>> execfile('C:\\test.py')
```

Use [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) for **Python 3**

```
>>> exec(open("C:\\test.py").read())
```

Comment: in the version 3 (my version) the equivalent is: exec(open("C:\\test.py").read()). thanks!

Comment: @loops I'm getting: `SyntaxError: (Unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uXXXX excape`. What does this mean?  I tried changing the encoding of my .py document to Unicode but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: @loops --Okay I just learned about `\U` unicode escapes. Apparetly you avoid his miscommunication by duplicating all backslashes followed by U's. But this produces an OSError 22 invalid argument `'c:\\users\username\\desktop\\test.py'` which is weird because I only duplicated the backslash in `\Users`. Why does the error show that I duplicated all the backslashes except for the one followed by username?

Comment: @Musixauce3000 Please [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: add an 'r' at the beginning if you get the SyntaxError: (Unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec... Therefore it will be,
exec(open(r"C:\\test.py").read()).

Comment: @phihag, the Python 3 version is verbose. Any expected problems defining `execfile = lambda file: exec(open(file).read())`?

Comment: @alancalvitti No, that sounds sensible if for whatever reason you want to execute files frequently.

Answer (score 54):

If you're wanting to run the script and end at a prompt (so you can inspect variables, etc), then use:

```
python -i test.py
```

That will run the script and then drop you into a Python interpreter.

Comment: How about if my script is not in a file?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa do you mean if it is coming in through a buffer or over the network?

Answer (score 20):

It depends on what is in `test.py`. The following is an appropriate structure:

```
# suppose this is your 'test.py' file
def main():
 """This function runs the core of your program"""
 print("running main")

if __name__ == "__main__":
 # if you call this script from the command line (the shell) it will
 # run the 'main' function
 main()
```

If you keep this structure, you can run it like this in the command line (assume that `$` is your command-line prompt):

```
$ python test.py
$ # it will print "running main"
```

If you want to run it from the Python shell, then you simply do the following:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.main() # this calls the main part of your program
```

There is no necessity to use the `subprocess` module if you are already using Python. Instead, try to structure your Python files in such a way that they can be run both from the command line and the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 6):

For newer version of python:

```
exec(open(filename).read())
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid writing all of this everytime, you can define a function :

```
def run(filename):
    exec(open(filename).read())
```

and then call it

```
run('filename.py')
```

Comment: This doesn't work for my use case since it doesn't import the variables. I'm not quite sure why not though.

Answer (score 2):

From the same folder, you can do:

```
import test
```