# run python file in python shell

Tags: ubuntu, python

I have a python file (`my_code.py`) in `Home/Python_Codes` folder in `ubuntu`. I want to run it in python shell. How can I do that?

I do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420937/run-program-in-python-shell)

`>>> execfile('~/Python_Codes/my_code.py')`

but it gives me path error

Comment: What's the exact, full path of the file? `Home/Python_Codes` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I gave you the folder structure in ubuntu. I can run my `.py` file in terminal using `python ~/Python_Codes/my_code.py`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should expand tilde(~) to actual path. Try following code.

In Python 2.x:

```
import os
execfile(os.path.expanduser('~/Python_Codes/my_code.py'))
```

In Python 3.x (no `execfile` in Python 3.x):

```
import os
with open(os.path.expanduser('~/Python_Codes/my_code.py')) as f:
    exec(f.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

Importing your module will execute any code at the top indent level - which includes creating any functions and classes you have defined there.

```
james@Brindle:/tmp$ cat my_codes.py

def myfunc(arg1, arg2):
    print "arg1: %s, arg2: %s" % (arg1, arg2)

print "hello"
james@Brindle:/tmp$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 14 2013, 22:12:26)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import my_codes
hello
>>> my_codes.myfunc("one", "two")
arg1: one, arg2: two
>>>
```

To add `~/Python_Codes` to the list of places that python will search, you can manipulate `sys.path` to add that directory to the start of the list.

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', ... '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
>>> sys.path.insert(0,'/home/me/Python_codes/')
>>> import my_codes
```

Answer (score 0):

import os,then excute os.system('~/Python_Codes/my_code.py'),maybe you need to change the path('~/Python_Codes/my_code.py') into a absolute path

Answer (score -1):

Go to Run >> cmd >> change directory to your Python folder , remember to put your file my_file.py into that folder. For example: if your Python folder in C drive, type

```
cd C:\Python
```

then type this

```
python my_file.py
```

the system will run your file.

Comment: I think this answer belongs to a different question; it doesn't solve the actual problem being asked about. Namely, how to run another file while already at a prompt.