# commands for executing a program in python shell

Tags: python-2.7

I need the exact commands to execute a program in the python shell in terminal.

My file is located in Home/Pictures/pythonpractice folder and its called fibonacci.py

which commands should I give to execute it in terminal.? please write the details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [run program in Python shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420937/run-program-in-python-shell)

Answer (score 0):

```
python Home/Pictures/pythonpractice/fibonacci.py
```