# How can I run a python script using the IPython console in Spyder?

Tags: python, bash, spyder

This command runs under `bash` on Linux:

```
python file.py variables
```

But when I write it to the IPython console in Spyder I get:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

*Q*: How can I run a python script using the IPython console in Spyder?

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To run a Python file in Spyder, you just need to open it in its editor and the go to the menu

```
Run > Run file
```

or press <kbd>F5</kbd>. That basically reads the contents of the file and executes it with `exec` (as it was suggested in the answer by Jeremy Hue).

If you want to pass arguments to your script, please see my answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26766414/438386).

Answer (score 0):

Your IPython console is already running Python, whereas the command `python file.py` in bash is basically saying 'run file.py using Python'.

Check out this solution if you want to run file.py explicitly via the IPython console
[run program in Python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420937/run-program-in-python-shell)

Comment: Hi thanks. The exec(open("C:\\test.py").read()) command is working good. But do you know how to add paramters/options when calling test.py?

Comment: I have this: python rsatool.py -f PEM -o key.pem -n 13826123222358393307 -d 9793706120266356337. How could I add all the paramters to the call? Thx

Comment: You will then have to change your approach. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788891/execute-a-file-with-arguments-in-python-shell