# Could someone show me a good factorial code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started to study Python. I must use Python3.7.
Could someone show me a working factorial code?
i tried some i found here but i always get this error:

```
=================== RESTART: C:\programozás\pytutorial.py ===================
```

Code:

```
def factorial(n):

      result = 1

      for i in range(1, n + 1):

            result *= i

      return result
```

Comment: What is the maximum value of `number` for which you want to calculate factorial?

Comment: That doesn't look like a Python error to me. Do you get a traceback? If so, can you provide one? Your code, as is, doesn't look like it should even produce an error.

Comment: I would be happy with 100.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I cant even run it, as i run the code, i get the error:

Comment: >>> 
=================== RESTART: C:\programozás\pytutorial.py ===================
>>>

Comment: i use Python 3.7.0 Shell

Comment: Your program doesn't do anything, it just creates a function `factorial`, but never calls it.

Comment: i changed the folder and i still can't run my code :/ >>> 
=================== RESTART: C:\programming\pytutorial.py ===================
>>>

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working, even though you could simply use the `math` library:

```
import math
print(math.factorial(5))
```

The problem does not come from your script, so maybe you should try to reinstall your python, and avoid paths with special characters as Adam Toth pointed out.

> Update: to get the input and return a factorial as asked in comments

```
import math
print(math.factorial(int(input(">>"))))
```

Comment: the code you sent will show 5! How can i make a code that will scan the numer i input and will show it's factorial?

Comment: What? The code I wrote will print **the factorial of 5**, not 5, that's the role of the [factorial function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/math.html#math.factorial)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did'nt saw the **!** char after your 5.

Comment: i reinstalled it, changed the folder and i have the same problem: >>> 
=================== RESTART: C:\programming\pytutorial.py ===================
>>>

Comment: import math
print(math.factorial(int(input(">>")))) What to do with this code to get the answer like Factorial of [n] is [i]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely caused because you have a special character in the path to the .py file. So should use a folder like C:\programming, or anything without a special character, like 'á'.

It's very important to do like this, even if it does not solve your current problem, it can prevent many more in the future.

*Ps.: Jó kiszúrni magyar programozót is :)*

Comment: Esetleg tudnál segíteni egy kicsit? (face, discord vagy valami) Akkor nem zavarnánk magyarul szegény angolokat. :)

Comment: @Daryl I know it is nice to meet people from your own country, but please speak English on SO ;-).

Comment: I just asked him to speak on an other platform so we do not disturb you with our language. :)

Answer (score 0):

I see a related (older) thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771625/simple-python-gui-program-wont-run-says-restart) about this error

For the logic:
We have to consider:

1. Negative numbers
2. Zero
3. Positive numbers

So one way to write it will be:

```
def factorial(n):
 if n < 0:
    result = "Factorial doesn't exist for negative numbers"
 elif n == 0:
    result = 1
 else:
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        result *= i
 return result
```

You can try the concept of recursion as well.

To get the factorial of a number "num":

```
print(factorial(num))
```

Make sure you indent the code properly, indentation is important in python.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried to run it. I get this error: =================== RESTART: C:\programming\pytutorial.py ===================

Comment: I see a related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771625/simple-python-gui-program-wont-run-says-restart) for the same error..

Comment: Thanks! So it has to contain print?

Comment: How can i make this in python?: printf("Enter a number: " scanf("%d", num)

Comment: if you are calling that function somewhere, it will return the result, otherwise if you want to see the result in console, yes you have to print it..

To accept input:
`num = int(input("Enter a number: "))`

Comment: Thanks! How can i use it in a sentence? Like: `import math
num = int(input("Which numbers factorial do you need?: "))
print (math.factorial(num))` <- I need to print -> Factorial of [num] is [result]

Answer (score 0):

Python Code of Factorial Using Recursive Function:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

factorial(5)
```

> **Note:** The First Condition will only meet when the input is 0 or 1 and in else block **n** will be recursively multiplying **n * n - 1**.