# running python script in interactive python prompt and keep the variables?

Tags: python

I understand from [How do I run a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522564/how-do-i-run-a-python-program) that in command prompt i can use

```
C:\python>python first.py
```

, to run `first.py`.

But, is it possible, that after i entered the interactive python prompt, by runnning

```
C:\python>python
```

and see the `>>>` python indication, run `first.py`, and after finished running `first.py`, back to the interactive python prompt, I could see variables defined inside `first.py`?

For example, if `first.py` created some variables inside, e.g. by

```
(x,y) = [3,5]
```

, is it possible that after running `first.py` and back to the interactive python prompt, `x` and `y` are still there?

[Running windows shell commands with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python) shows how to run the windows shell command in python, so in the interactive python prompt, i could actually use

```
>>>os.system('python first.py')
```

to run `first.py`, but `x` and `y` defined inside are lost after running.

Comment: try `import first` from prompt

Comment: If you did not put the code into `if __name__ == "__main__":`, you can just do `import first`.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov then is it possible to keep variables in `first.py` after running?

Comment: @tobias_k same question...

Comment: @athos: you can get objects from module using dot notation

Comment: @AzatIbrakov thx!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the following for Python 2.x:

```
>>> execfile('first.py')
```

For Python 3.x, try this:

```
>>> exec(open("./first.py").read())
```

The variables should then be available to you.

Comment: somehow it returns error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined

Comment: @athos You maybe on Python 3; check the updated answer.

Comment: thx it's working!

Comment: The Python 3.x version works for me

Answer (score 17):

Use

```
C:\python>python -i first.py
```

to run the script and get the interactive shell in the same namespace afterwards.

Comment: This way the script is executed the same way OP does it right now, with added interactive shell. `import` would indeed not work with a `if __name__ == "__main__":`-statement.