# Running python script on CMD which uses a folder to output results

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt, python-3.6

I was using Pycharm as my editor to run the scripts since i need to add a task scheduler i had to test the code on the command prompt. Firstly this is the structure of my project.
[image]

When i try to run the following line

```
C:\Users\My_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe "C:\Users\My_name\PycharmProjects\FYP_CB006302\generateSummary.py"
```

I get this error,
[image]

From the knowledge i have i think it is because it doesn't recognize the path.

But when i change the directory to my project folder then give the path to python.exe and type generateSummary.py it works which was done as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527012/8373304).

However i highly doubt that this method can be used to task a schedule in Windows. Therefore, any ideas that would to run as shown in the beginning will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when you use that line to run a particular script the folder which is causing the error is out of scope.

```
  C:\Users\My_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe "C:\Users\My_name\PycharmProjects\FYP_CB006302\generateSummary.py"
```

In this case `pickle_saves` folder is out of scope. You can avoid this by giving a absolute path to that file in `line 173`. Where the absolute path is something like `C:\user\documents\projects\pickle_saves\all_words`

Comment: Yes, you are correct i figured it out. Thank you anyway! :)